# Salesforce External API not deserializing

Tags: java, api, salesforce, apex

I am relativly new to salesforce and apex programming. Recently I am assigned to get data from an external api. I am receiving an object which also has another object inside the main object. the data I am suppose to  receive is as follows

```json
{
    "Product_Catagories": [{
        "id": "8ad08aef8534de220185400383d82def",
        "name": "Product One",
        "description": "Desc One",
        "region": "",
        "category": "Main Products",
        "ProductFamily": "Main",
        "RelatedProducts": "POC-B0000001",
        "productfeatures": []
    }, {
        "id": "8ad0887e8534de2701853fff5a9b22ee",
        "name": "Product Two",
        "description": "Desc Two",
        "region": "",
        "category": "Main Products",
        "ProductFamily": "Main",
        "RelatedProducts": "POC-B0000002",
        "productfeatures": []
    }, {
        "id": "8ad08aef8534de2201853ffe48fc08f6",
        "name": "Product Three",
        "description": "Desc Three",
        "region": "",
        "category": "Main Products",
        "ProductFamily": "Main",
        "RelatedProducts": "POC-B0000003",
        "productfeatures": []
    }]
}
```

but i am getting

`Product_Catagories:[category=null, description=null, id=null, name=null, productFamily=null, productfeatures=null, region=null, relatedProducts=null]`

I have defined classes in apex code but the object is coming as empty. No data is showing. The code I am using is as follows

```
public class POCGetCategories {
    
    public static List<Product_Catagories> getPOCCats(){
        
        return new List<Product_Catagories>{getPOCProducts()};
        
    }
    
    public class Product_Catagories {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String description;
        public String region;
        public String category; 
        public String productFamily;
        public String relatedProducts;
        public POCProductfeature productfeatures;
    }

    public class POCProductfeature {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public String code;
        public String status;
        public String description;
    }

    private static Product_Catagories getPOCProducts(){
            
            Product_Catagories cats = new Product_Catagories();
            Http h = new Http();
                String method = 'GET';
                String url = 'https://externalapi';
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

                req.setEndpoint(url);
                req.setMethod(method);      
                req.setTimeout(120000);
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jsson');
                req.setHeader('subscription-Key','db163fc326d***');
                HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
            cats = (Product_Catagories)System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Product_Catagories.class);
            system.debug('Data: ' + cats);
            return cats;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ is excellent for stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

The main response object is an object with a "Product_Catagories" key that contains an array of individual categories. The features key in each category is a list as well. Your model should look something like this:

```java
public class ProductCatagoriesResponse {
    public List<Product_Catagory> Product_Catagories;
}

public class Product_Catagory {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String region;
    public String category; 
    public String productFamily;
    public String relatedProducts;
    public List<POCProductfeature> productfeatures;
}

...

ProductCatagoriesResponse cats = (ProductCatagoriesResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), ProductCatagoriesResponse.class);
```

Also, it's spelled "category." But I'm assuming that's their typo and you just have to deal with it...

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes in the object but It is still not deserializing. Object is still showing null values no data.

Comment: Can you system.debug your HttpResponse object and add it in an edit to your original question?